# JAVA: Adding new buttons to a scrollable panel

Tags: java

I am building a simple game and I need a grid with buttons of various colors. The grid should be 10 buttons in width and unbounded in height. There is an extra button at the bottom, which clones the already existing buttons onto the same grid. I need to keeps the sizes of the buttons the same as well as for a scroll bar to appear when adding too many buttons.

Some visuals of my problem can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOFl5.jpg).

I tried using a JScrollPane and I put the main JPanel inside of it, but the scroll bar doesn't appear. I am quite new at this, so any tips on how to deal with this would be much appreciated

My code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Main {
    private JFrame window;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel currentButtonsPanel;

    private ArrayList<JButton> buttons;

    private final int WINDOW_X, WINDOW_Y;
    private final int N_BUTTONS = 10;

    private final Color[] colors = new Color[]{
            Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,
            Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.MAGENTA};
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private JButton selectedButton = null;

    public Main(int w, int h, String title){
        WINDOW_X = w;
        WINDOW_Y = h;


        window = new JFrame(title);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        //mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        buttons = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < N_BUTTONS*3.5; i++)
            addNewButton();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        window.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(generateButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel generateButtonsPanel(){
        JPanel ret = new JPanel();

        JButton btn = new JButton("Check");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                copyButtons();
            }
        });
        ret.add(btn);

        return ret;
    }

    private void copyButtons(){
        ArrayList<JButton> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(JButton btn : buttons){
            JButton newBtn = new JButton();
            newBtn.setBackground(btn.getBackground());
            newBtn.addActionListener(btn.getActionListeners()[0]);
            newList.add(newBtn);
        }
        for(JButton btn : newList)
            addNewButton(btn);
    }

    private void addNewButton(){
        JButton newButton = new JButton();

        Color col = colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)];
        newButton.setBackground(col);

        newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();
                if(selectedButton == null){
                    selectedButton = btn;
                    btn.setText(".");
                    return;
                }
                if(selectedButton == btn){
                    selectedButton = null;
                    btn.setText("");
                    return;
                }
                if(selectedButton.getBackground() == btn.getBackground()){
                    System.out.println("Matching!");
                    btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    selectedButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    btn.setEnabled(false);
                    selectedButton.setEnabled(false);

                    buttons.remove(btn);
                    buttons.remove(selectedButton);
                }else
                    System.out.println("No match!");

                btn.setText("");
                selectedButton.setText("");
                selectedButton = null;
            }
        });

        addNewButton(newButton);
    }

    private void addNewButton(JButton btn){
        if(buttons.size() % 10 == 0){
            currentButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
            currentButtonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,10));
            currentButtonsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_X*WINDOW_X,WINDOW_X/N_BUTTONS+10));
            currentButtonsPanel.add(btn);
            mainPanel.add(currentButtonsPanel);
        }else
            currentButtonsPanel.add(btn);
        buttons.add(btn);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main(400, 300, "Game");
    }
}
```

EDIT: This code is only experimental, so far I'm only interested in the technical aspects of this program, so everything is simplified.

Comment: What did you set your scroll bar policy to?  Can you post a snippet of code where your ScrollPane being initialized and set up?  Since you said you're new, you may also want to have a gander at [the scrollpane tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollbars) and the [JScrollPane Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) to make sure you didn't miss anything.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I edited my post to include the code. It's still very experimental though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is with `currentButtonsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_X*WINDOW_X,WINDOW_X/N_BUTTONS+10));`.  The purpose of that method is to indicate to the Layout Manager the maximum size that the particular component will ever be, rather than telling it to set to that size.  They layout manager has automatically determined what size your JPanel should be (as well as the buttons inside), and is following through with that determination in order to avoid using the scroll bar, all the while (correctly) obeying the Max size directive you gave it.

Try `setPreferredSize()` instead; this tells your Layout Manager the size that your component wants to be.  This will cause the Layout Manager to set the JPanel to your preferred size, which should cause a vertical scrollbar to appear, given that you have a vertical scrolling policy set up.

Comment: Thank you! This worked but at first the buttons were still stretched. However I combined `setPrefferedSize()` with `setMaximumSize()` and `setMinimumSize()` and it worked like a charm.